# Search workbook from combobox list and return data in textbox

Tags: vba, combobox, textbox

I have a combobox on a userform populated with dates from a range in Column A in a workbook. I want to return the data in Columns C and D into a textbox... It's been a few years since I dabbled with VBA so I'm more than a little rusty, here's what I have

```
Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Sheets(“Log”).Range(“A” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LastRow

If Sheets(“Log”).Cells(i, “A”).Value = (Me.CBsupplier2) Or _
Sheets(“Log”).Cells(i, “A”).Value = Val(Me.CBsupplier2) Then
    Me.TBdata = Sheets(“Log”).Cells(i, “A”).Value
    Me.TBdata = Sheets(“Log”).Cells(i, “C”).Value
    Me.TBdata = Sheets(“Log”).Cells(i, “D”).Value
End If
```

There's probably a step I've forgotten but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is wrong with your code? Which errors you get? Note that those smart quotes `“` are not allowed in VBA and need to be replaced with the standard ones `"`.

Comment: What do you mean by *"I want to return the data in Columns C and D into a textbox"*? Please give some example data and the result you expect. Your entire goal is pretty unclear.